# Chrome extension : storing variables in background page is secure?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'd like to know if storing some information in variables in the background page raises security problems ?

Could a website or an another extension get access to these variables ?

I currently have an extension with a login system (I store a hash of the password in the localStorage so I compare hashes when users attempt to connect to the system).
I am thinking of extending it with a module that would keep a password in memory until log out or time out. I don't want to use the localStorage to store the password in clear so I thought to store it in the background page, but it might be worse ...

If this is not secure, could you give me a tip about how implementing such module ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Other extensions and websites cannot access the storage of your background page, unless you implement this feature yourself.

**Saving data at your extension's background page is as secure as Chrome's password manager.**
<sub>Chrome stores its credentials without encryption in a SQLite database at `profile directory/Default/Login Data`</sub>

Data from [`chrome.storage`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage.html), localStorage, HTML5 filesystem, IndexedDB, etc. are saved in Chrome's profile directory. Anyone with access to your profile directory can read the data. Anyone who opens the devtools for background page can view the stored values.

If the profile directory is safe, you don't need to worry about the security of the method.
Otherwise, you have to make a trade-off between convenience and security. Is it acceptable to keep asking the user for the password? Then try saving session identifiers, and ask for credentials when a session has expired. Or use oAuth.

### Read more

- [Tutorial: oAuth](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_oauth.html) at the Chrome extensions documentation.
- [Password storing in Google Chrome content scripts](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/35688/password-storing-in-google-chrome-content-scripts) at Security.SE.
- [How can I protect my saved passwords in Chrome?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/7134/how-can-i-protect-my-saved-passwords-in-chrome/7135#7135) at Security.SE

Comment: @user2518293 You're welcome. What have you decided? Are you going to store the credentials in plain text?

Comment: When someone creates a new profile in my extension, I store a hash of the password in the localStorage, so even if someone gets access to the devtools or Chrome's profile directory then it's not in clear.(Actually I ask the user for a passphrase rather than a simple password, so the hash stored cannot be brutforced) And if a user wants the extension to remember its password for x minutes, then I store the password into the background page in clear and use the timeOut function to delete the password after x minutes. what do you think about that ?

Comment: @user2518293 By "store", I hope that you meant "save in a variable"? If you save the value in localStorage, and close the browser before `setTimeout` had a chance to kick in, then the value would not be deleted. You haven't given enough detail to judge whether it's secure or not (I'm afraid that it's not secure). 1) Is it necessary to store the credentials at all? 2) How and by what is the hash generated? 3) Is this used for authentication or identification? 4) Why can't you save a session identifier at the server's instead of the credentials at the client?

Comment: Yes I meant save in a variable. 1.) I let the user decides whether or not he wants the extension to temporary save its password. 2.) I use Stanford Javascript library to compute the hash, using sha256. 3.) Identification 4.) There is no server, that's why the password must be saved at the client. To better understand, my extension secure email communications. it allows users to establish a symmetric key using HCBK protocol then use it to encrypt/decrypt emails. I use a system of login/passphrase so no other user of a the computer can send email using the symmetric key.

Comment: @user2518293 The way of storage sounds OK. If possible, I would also include an unique salt, to guard against rainbow tables. I'm not qualified to judge whether the encryption methods you use are sufficiently strong. If you want to know more about that, create an account at http://security.stackexchange.com/ and ask a question over there.

Comment: Is it valid for firefox's extension as well?

Comment: @ShivanshuGoyal Yes.