# Chrome extension security - Who can access background, content and internal scripts?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, security

I would like to know if this procedure is safe :

- I save (with encryption JS AES & Passphrase) data into local/sync storage
- The data is decrypted in the popup and in the background script
- I sent the decrypted data into https URL as "GET" method

Can someone (beside the user who has the extension) access :

- The passphrase hard coded in background script / internal script (by internal I mean popup.js, the script that works with the popup when the popup is open)
- The GET data sent to HTTPS URL

Thanks,

Regards,

Martin

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17287553/chrome-extension-storing-variables-in-background-page-is-secure